# Using the product rule when differentiating

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I am asked to find $dy/dx$ if $y = x(2x + 5)^7$ using the product rule.

I have made $U = X$ and differentiated this to get $1$.

And $V = (2x + 5)^7$ and differentiated to get $7(2x + 5)^6$.

However the solutions say that $V'$ should be $14(2x + 5)^6$.

Should it be $7$ and not $14$ ? Has there been an error in the solutions or am I incorrect ?

By the way I got $U$ and $V$ from:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = U \cdot \frac{dV}{dx} + V \cdot \frac{dU}{dx}
$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chain Rule for Derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here, is that you have not used the chain rule.

Put simply, the chain rule says:

$\text{ If you have a function composed of another function }$

$\text{ you must take derivative of outside function $\times$ derivative of inside function }$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ f(g(x))\right] = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$

---

In our case here, we have $(2x+5)^7$. What you must recognize is that this is a combination of $(2x+5)$ and $x^7$.

So we get that the derivative of $(2x+5)^7$ is:

$$7*(2x+5)^6 \text { (product rule on the outside $x^7$ function)} \times (2) \text {(linear differentiation of 2x + 5)} $$

$$14(2x+5)^6$$

Answer (score -1):

You can not apply the reasoning that $\frac{d}{dx}(2x+5)^7 = 7(2x+5)^6$. You have attempted to apply the power rule to a function that is not a polynomial term, and the power rule applies only to functions of the form $ax^n$. Instead, you may do two things:

- Expand and apply power rule to each individual term (slow)
- Apply the chain rule

The latter of these options you may not have been introduced to you, so here it is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ f(g(x))\right] = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x)$$